# White-listing an ip in spring project

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, whitelist

I have a simple java application with login. It has a SecurityConfig class which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. And I have implemented couple of methods there

```
void configure(WebSecurity web)
void configure(HttpSecurity http)
```

In the configure(WebSecurity web) method, i'm ignoring authentication for certain URL's

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
    .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/examplePattern");
}
```

I have some service endpoints in this project.Now I need to white-list a certain ip (which I have as a string array), which should be able to access only a specific endpoint. This is because all the calls to the endpoints go through the user login authentication.

Basically what I need is, if a certain endpoint is called from a specific IP, the request should reach the controller,without authenticating

I'm quite new to this area, so if you have a solution for this problem, please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will require IP address based authentication provider as follows :

```
@Service 
public class IPAddressBasedAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {


     @Autowired
     private HttpServletRequest request;

     @Override
     public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

         String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
         // Check against your array.
         //return created authentication object (if user provided valid credentials)
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm looking for a way that if the ipaddress matches, i should not authenticate, but that request should go through.

Comment: Go through from what?

Comment: The request should reach the controller without an authentication. Basically what I need is, if a certain endpoint is called from a specific IP, the request should reach the controller,without authenticating.

Comment: If you just call the controller mapping in your JSP, it will reach. I still don't understand what you want, maybe some other user might be able to help.

Comment: All the calls to the controller will go through security where we validate whether a user has logged in. What I want is, if it's from a specific IP trying to reach a specific endpoint, without checking for the authentication.